# Why after "reloadCollectionViewDataAtIndexPath(index)", some cell disappear?

Tags: ios, swift

in the func

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

I use

```
if let imageData_ = imageData{
        cell.setImage(UIImage(data: imageData_))
    }
    else{
        cell.setImage(nil)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
            var Data = self.getImageFromModel(point, index: indexPath.item)
            if let Data_ = Data{
                self.imageCache.setObject(Data_, forKey: NSString(format: "%d", indexPath.item))
                NSLog("Download Image for %d", indexPath.item)

                self.reloadCollectionViewDataAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            }
            else{
                println("nil Image")
            }

        })
    }

func reloadCollectionViewDataAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath){
    var indexArray = NSArray(object: indexPath)
    self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexArray)
}
```

to load image from web,but after loading all the picture,some cells that are out of the initial scene disappear(below the initial scene,can scroll the view)

but if I scroll the view to make the missing cells visible before load all the images completely,everything is fine...

where is the problem..?

Comment: you should call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` in main thread.

Comment: What you said does works!Thanks!!!